# Moving files using shutil.move is too slow

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to move files from one folder to another in the same HD using the `shutil.move`. However the process is taking so much time to complete. Commonly in these operations there are too many files (almost 2,000) and together these files have more than 1TB in total.

I looked over the `shutil.move` documentation and there is explained that the `shutil.move` uses a copy function behind it (I guess this is why the process is so slow):

> **[shutil.move(src, dst, copy_function=copy2)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)**
>
> Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst) and return the destination.
>
> If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a
> directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.
>
> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied to dst using copy_function and then
> removed. In case of symlinks, a new symlink pointing to the target of
> src will be created in or as dst and src will be removed.
>
> If copy_function is given, it must be a callable that takes two arguments src and dst, and will be used to copy src to dst if
> os.rename() cannot be used. If the source is a directory, copytree()
> is called, passing it the copy_function(). The default copy_function
> is copy2(). Using copy() as the copy_function allows the move to
> succeed when it is not possible to also copy the metadata, at the
> expense of not copying any of the metadata.

I already tried to change between the copy functions presented in the `shutil.move` docs, but this didn't improved the time moving the files.

When I try to move the files by myself using `ctrl + X`, the files are moved instantanely. Anybody knows if there is an alternative method to the `shutil.move` that I can use which has the same performance of an `ctrl + X` command?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I put all the files that I want to move inside a folder, and then perfom the `shutil.move`, so my code is just:

```
src_folder = 'C:/Users/sim/Documents/files_to_move'
dst_folder = 'C:/Users/sim/Documents/_out/'

shutil.move(src_folder, dst_folder)
```

Also I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: Ctrl-X is a shortcut for a cut operation. How does that relate to copying a file from one place to another? Also, shutil.move() will (effectively) implement *mv* (on Unix-like systems) which will be very fast as the file isn't actually copied when source and target are on the same filesystems. Please show your code and let us know what OS you're working with

Comment: Cut files from one folder to another (move) is exactly what I want. But it seems to me that `shutil.move` is coping the files from the source folder to the destination folder. This hypotesis came in because I can actually see the files "appearing" in the destination folder as the `shutil.move` runs. And I guess this copy procedure is what is costing me too much time. My code is simple as: `shutil.move(folder_a, folder_b)`. And I am running it on windows 10.

Comment: Are the source and destination on the same filesystem, or is the move between two separate filesystems? You'll only ever get constant-time performance (or, rather, performance that scales by number of items to move as opposed to size of those items) in the former case.

Comment: That you see files appearing one at a time doesn't tell us anything useful. The important question is whether the data blocks behind those files are being rewritten or just having the directory entry that points to them updated. It's still plausible to see files appear one at a time in the latter case if your filesystem is for some reason ridiculously slow.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with you @CharlesDuffy . Is there any way to check if the blocks are being rewritten or just having the directory updated? And yes, the filesystem is the same in both source and destination folders.

Comment: The surest approach is to trace execution. You could do that at syscall level with tools like `strace` (or whatever the Windows equivalent is), or at Python level with `python -m trace`.

Comment: Ok, I will test it here and keep you posted. Thanks @CharlesDuffy !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why I was having this issue when using `shutil.move`.

I am working with the same filesystem (In the same hard drive as well) and when I was performing `shutil.move(src, dst)` the process takes hours to finish, and when I do it manually (using the `ctrl-X` shortcut) the same files were moved instantly.

I manage to solve the problem using `os.rename` instead, and now it works perfectly (the files are being moved fast as using `ctrl-X` shortcut). I will leave this answer here if someone else face the same problem, maybe this could help in some way.

Comment: I suspect the cause is that shutil.move() is actually silently using copy_function under the hood (according to the documentation this is possible if the move function fails)